# Change write location for neo4j-admin import

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to import around 300G of csv data to neo4j using the neo4j-admin import tool. However, the directory in which neo4j is stored does not have that much space available.

How do I change the directory that the import tool writes to? I tried:

```
--database= /new/directory/my.graphdb
```

but got the following:

```
'database' should be a name but you seem to have specified a path:
```

Can anyone explain how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As a quick workaround, you can use the (deprecated) neo4j-import tool that has a `--into` argument. For an example, see the "Super Fast Batch Importer For Huge Datasets" section of the [CSV Import Guide](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/):

```
bin/neo4j-import --into retail.db --id-type string \
                 --nodes:Customer customers.csv --nodes products.csv  \
                 --nodes orders_header.csv,orders1.csv,orders2.csv \
                 --relationships:CONTAINS order_details.csv \
                 --relationships:ORDERED customer_orders_header.csv,orders1.csv,orders2.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You specify the *directory* of a neo4j database in the [dbms.directories.data](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.2/reference/configuration-settings/#config_dbms.directories.data) property of the neo4j configuration file (which can be found at the location specified [in this table](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.2/configuration/file-locations/#file-locations), based on your environment). The directory can be specified as a relative path or an absolute path.

The `--database` [option of neo4j-admin](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/import/options/#import-tool-options) only specifies the name of the database file, not the directory.